# Is it possible to install Office 2019 on Windows 10 install.esd?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I downloaded the "Office 2019 x64" .iso from Microsoft. Now I want to install office on Windows 10 image(install.esd). So, the next time when I install Windows 10, Office 2019 will be preinstalled.

Comment: I find an article "[Deploy Microsoft 365 Apps as part of an operating system image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/deploy-microsoft-365-apps-operating-system-image)", but I do not know whether it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot preinstall Office into the Windows 10 ISO.

PC manufacturers and builders install Windows 10, then boot it up into a special mode that allows modifications to the preinstalled applications and default user profile. When they are done, the PC is booted back into normal mode. Then the new owner receives the new PC and is prompted to create a user account, as if Windows was freshly installed.

That is called customizing the Out of Box Experience. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-oobe

If you need to deploy a custom installation of Windows, this is how you do it. You configure a new PC with Windows 10, and set it up through the OOBE. Then you image that PC, and deploy the image.